# Calling $_SESSION variables from $_POST data across PHP files?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying as best I can to get these variables crossing onto a receipt page but it's just not working.

I have a form in index.php which takes user input which I then want to be added into tools.php to process it (ie checking for errors) and once processed, it is to be outputted in receipt.php.

I'm very new to php so i apologise if this isn't great.

My form from index.php is as follows

```
<input type="text" id="cust-name" class="input-field" name="cust[name]" value="" />
```

heading into tools.php

```
  session_start();

  if ($_POST){
  $cleanName = $_POST['cust']['name'];
  };
```

And finally in receipt.php

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['$cleanName'];
```

It's just not working and I keep getting a Undefined Index error.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you actually adding the value to the session? Or are you trying to use the value from the post as key? Please edit your question to clarify what the you're trying to accomplish since it's very unclear at the moment.

Comment: Problem 1) Where are you *storing* the session variable?  EXAMPLE: `$_SESSION['cleanName'] =  $_POST['cust']['name'];`. Problem 2): the syntax `echo $_SESSION['$cleanName'];` references the [string literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) `$cleanName`.  Not what you want ;)

Comment: I'm very sorry I'm so new to PHP I'm struggling a lot with it. I'm trying to access the user-input data from the HTML form using the POST method and then trying to use that data via $_POST to be passed into $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

To assign the value you have to use the session variable.

Assign like this:

```
$_SESSION["cleanName"] = $_POST[..][..]
```

When you access the value you shouldn’t use the $ sign:

```
echo $_SESSION["cleanName"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's showing the error because you've not set values into SESSION variable. To get session you supposed to set it first.

For example when you handling the Post request you've to assign session variable with the key name that you can letter access throughout your website.

**tool.php**

```
session_start();

if ($_POST){
    $cleanName = $_POST['cust']['name'];
    $_SESSION['cleanName'] = $cleanName;
};
```

**receipt.php**

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['cleanName'];
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't set earlier and that they aren't trying to use the value of the post as session key? IMHO, there isn't enough info yet to know what they really are trying to do.